# error:not authorized on cuckoo(DB name) to execute command using (cuckoo with mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use mongoDB with cuckoo but i get this error message :

```
2016-12-16 06:58:01,632 [lib.cuckoo.core.plugins] ERROR: Failed to run the reporting module "MongoDB":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ziv/Documents/cuckoo/lib/cuckoo/core/plugins.py", line 533, in process
    current.run(self.results)
  File "/home/ziv/Documents/cuckoo/modules/reporting/mongodb.py", line 89, in run
    if "cuckoo_schema" in self.db.collection_names():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 520, in collection_names
    results = self._list_collections(sock_info, slave_okay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 492, in _list_collections
    cursor = self._command(sock_info, cmd, slave_okay)["cursor"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 393, in _command
    allowable_errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 211, in command
    read_concern)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 100, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, msg, allowable_errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 196, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: command SON([('listCollections', 1), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace cuckoo.$cmd failed: not authorized on cuckoo to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {} }
```

this is the DB's i have:

```
 show dbs 
    admin   0.078GB 
    cuckoo  0.078GB 
    local   0.078GB
```

i used this guide to install mongo db https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16.04/

i used this guide to install cuckoo
http://mostlyaboutsecurity.com/?p=15&i=1

**update**

ithink i dont have permissions but i dont know how to set up what i need,
this is the cuckoo code that uses mongo DB:
 (on this line "self.db.collection_names():")

```
 def run(self, results):
        """Writes report.
        @param results: analysis results dictionary.
        @raise CuckooReportError: if fails to connect or write to MongoDB.
        """
        if not HAVE_MONGO:
            raise CuckooDependencyError(
                "Unable to import pymongo (install with "
                "`pip install pymongo`)"
            )

        self.connect()

        # Set mongo schema version.
        # TODO: This is not optimal becuase it run each analysis. Need to run
        # only one time at startup.
        if "cuckoo_schema" in self.db.collection_names():
            if self.db.cuckoo_schema.find_one()["version"] != self.SCHEMA_VERSION:
                CuckooReportError("Mongo schema version not expected, check data migration tool")
        else:
            self.db.cuckoo_schema.save({"version": self.SCHEMA_VERSION})

 def connect(self):
        """Connects to Mongo database, loads options and set connectors.
        @raise CuckooReportError: if unable to connect.
        """
        host = self.options.get("host", "127.0.0.1")
        port = int(self.options.get("port", 27017))
        db = self.options.get("db", "cuckoo")

        try:
            self.conn = MongoClient(host, port)
            self.db = self.conn[db]
            self.fs = GridFS(self.db)
        except TypeError:
            raise CuckooReportError("Mongo connection port must be integer")
        except ConnectionFailure:
            raise CuckooReportError("Cannot connect to MongoDB")
```

I don't want to edit this code (add connection string to it)

I have a clean installation of MongoDB, how do i create a DB named cuckoo
that this code can acsess and use?

I couldn't find any reference in all the guides I read. its like it should work automaticly but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The error message is:

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('listCollections', 1), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace cuckoo.$cmd failed: not authorized on cuckoo to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {} }
```

This indicates that your app is attempting to execute a command in the MongoDB database for which it does not have permissions.

- Does your connection string to the database include the authentication credentials (username/password)?
- Does this user have necessary permissions to execute this command?

Comment: there is no user in the connection string code (I've updated my question with the cuckoo code accessing MongoDB ).

Comment: the cuckoo proc is running under a regular user of the system

I don't know how to add this permissions to this user

Comment: Is your MongoDB instance running with auth enabled? i.e. Do you need to pass a username and password when connecting to the database with the mongo shell? If so, you will need to include the username and password in your connection code when connecting to MongoDB. See https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#scram-sha-1-rfc-5802 for an example.